# Sorting files per directory using SPL's DirectoryTreeIterator

Tags: php, sorting, recursion, iterator, spl

I found a couple of questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076881/after-using-files-new-directoryiterator-in-php-how-do-you-sort-the-items) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930405/sort-directory-listing-using-recursivedirectoryiterator)) related to the SPL iterators, but I'm not sure if they're helpful in my case, as I'm using a rather high level extension of the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`; the `DirectoryTreeIterator`.

Could somebody perhaps show me how to alter the `DirectoryTreeIterator` or how to sort the returned array per directory after it has been outputted by the iterator?

A method of sorting the files correctly directly on the Apache server is also an option for me, if it's possible using `.htaccess` for example.

This is the code of `DirectoryTreeIterator` from the SPL:

```
/** @file directorytreeiterator.inc
 * @ingroup Examples
 * @brief class DirectoryTreeIterator
 * @author  Marcus Boerger
 * @date    2003 - 2005
 *
 * SPL - Standard PHP Library
 */

/** @ingroup Examples
 * @brief   DirectoryIterator to generate ASCII graphic directory trees
 * @author  Marcus Boerger
 * @version 1.1
 */

class DirectoryTreeIterator extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    /** Construct from a path.
     * @param $path directory to iterate
     */
    function __construct($path) {
        parent::__construct(
            new RecursiveCachingIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME
                ), 
                CachingIterator::CALL_TOSTRING|CachingIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
            ), 
            parent::SELF_FIRST
        );
    }

    /** @return the current element prefixed with ASCII graphics
     */ 
    function current() {
        $tree = '';
        for ($l=0; $l < $this->getDepth(); $l++) {
            $tree .= $this->getSubIterator($l)->hasNext() ? ' ' : ' ';
        }
        return $tree . ($this->getSubIterator($l)->hasNext() ? ' ' : ' ') 
               . $this->getSubIterator($l)->__toString();
    }

    /** Aggregates the inner iterator
     */ 
    function __call($func, $params) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->getSubIterator(), $func), $params);;
    }
}
```

To clarify why I'm using the code above is because it fits my needs exactly. I want to generate a recursive directory tree prefixed by whitespaces - the original code example by Marcus Boerger adds some ASCI elements. The problem is I don't have control over the sorting of files and directories, so I would like the directory tree to appear like this:

```
dir001
  subdir001
    subdir002
      subfile001.jpg
  file001.png
  file002.png
  file003.png
dir002
  apple.txt
  bear.txt
  contact.txt
dir003
[...]
```

Instead, the listings returned by the iterator isn't sorted at all and it shows me something like this:

```
dir002
  bear.txt
  apple.txt
  contact.txt
dir001
  subdir001
    subdir002
      subfile001.jpg
  file002.png
  file001.png
  file003.png
dir003
[...]
```

So I guess the solution I'm looking for is some way to call a sort method every time a subdirectory is indexed and added to the directory tree.

I hope I've made it somewhat clearer, as a nonnative speaker it's sometimes hard to put thoughts into coherent sentences (or even words for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure where you got that class from, but it's doing some pretty messed up things (including a few bugs to say the least).  And while it uses SPL, it's not an SPL class.

Now, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "sort", but assuming you're talking about a natural sort, why not just flatten an array, and then sort it?

```
$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(
    new RecrusiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
    RecursiveTreeIterator::BYPASS_KEY,
    CachingIterator::CALL_TOSTRING
);
$files = iterator_to_array($it);
natsort($files);
echo implode("\n", $files);
```

or

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$files = iterator_to_array($it);
$files = array_map(function($file) { return (string) $file; }, $files);
natsort($files);
echo implode("\n", $files);
```

**Edit:** Based on your edit, here's how I would solve it:

```
function BuildTree($it, $separator = '  ', $level = '') {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($it as $file) {
        if (in_array($file->getBasename(), array('.', '..'))) {
            continue;
        }
        $tmp = $level . $file->getBaseName();
        if ($it->hasChildren()) {
            $newLevel = $level . $separator;
            $tmp .= "\n" . BuildTree($it->getChildren(), $separator, $newLevel);
        }
        $results[] = $tmp;
    }
    natsort($results);
    return implode("\n", $results);
};
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$tree = BuildTree($it);
```

It's a pretty simple recursive parser, and does the natural sort on each level.

Comment: I think you're right about the iterator not being part of SPL, but it's listed in the examples: http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/dir_e16bad08fe0100cb7c8253fd4ebce86a.html and here: http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/directorytreeiterator_8inc.html

Comment: @mensch Well, that's just an example usage.  Not to mention that it appears that you've modified it (hence introducing the bugs I was talking about).  If you give an example of what you're after, perhaps we can better help...

Comment: You're right I altered the code a bit so that it outputs whitespaces instead of the ASCII characters. At first glance, I can't spot any other differences between the original example and my version, though. The reason why I choose to incorporate the example is because I want to generate the directorytree prefixed with whitespaces. I'll update my question with a bit of extra information as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks a million! Always have a hard time wrapping my head around recursion. I've just replaced the old code with your BuildTree method and it's working well now. I replaced $file->getBaseName() with $file->getPathname() because I need the full path to the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about SPL iterators, but for your iterator you should put the items in an array, then sort them and add them to $tree. I modified the function **current** but didn't test it:

```
function current()
{
    $tree = '';

    $treeitems = array();
    for ($l=0; $l < $this->getDepth(); $l++) {
        //NOTE: On this line I think you have an error in your original code:
        //      This ? ' ' : ' ' is strange
        $treeitems[] = $this->getSubIterator($l)->hasNext() ? ' ' : ' ';
    }
    $treeitems.sort();
    for each ($treeitems as $treeitem)
        $tree .= $treeitem;

    return $tree . ($this->getSubIterator($l)->hasNext() ? ' ' : ' ') 
           . $this->getSubIterator($l)->__toString();
}
```