# Building A Log Reader with PHP RecursiveTreeIterator

Tags: php, oop, iterator, directory-structure, spl

I have this dir structure for logs

```
logs
-2012
--01
---01.php
---02.php
--02
---20.php
---23.php
```

I want to be able to use PHP's RecursiveTreeIterator to be able to display a tree having actual php files(not dirs) as links to display the file contents.

Using the first answer in this question as a guide: [Sorting files per directory using SPL's DirectoryTreeIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5417487/153632)

I am new to most of PHP 5's SPL so I need some help here. How do I build the tree? Thanks!

Comment: if you just want to list the files, you dont need the treeIterator. The treeIterator is for printing an ASCII tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII Library for Creating "Pretty" Directory Trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196368/208809) (remove the `SELF_FIRST` constant and it should list only the files/leaves)

Comment: should I rephrase that? I have tried different approaches, the link given and the DirectoryIterator approach. Gordon, is there not any way to retrieve file information from this ASCII tree, or it does just print?

Comment: @Ygam Like I said, the treeIterator will print an ASCII tree. So you cannot get at the iterated file in a `foreach`. However, you can use a `for` loop to iterate it and then access the iterated files by accessing the inner Iterator from the treeIterator.

Comment: I was asking that so that I can display the files as links that points to the file path

Comment: The question remains: do you actually need the ASCII tree or do you just need to display the files as links?

Comment: both. I need a tree to quickly navigate through the log directories, then display each log file in the tree as links

Comment: Please check whether http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739 solves your problem (you need to adjust the markup to your needs and use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` instead of the `ArrayIterator` of course)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII Library for Creating "Pretty" Directory Trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581559/ascii-library-for-creating-pretty-directory-trees)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to the links I provided in the comments already:

- [ASCII Library for Creating "Pretty" Directory Trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581559/ascii-library-for-creating-pretty-directory-trees/4196368#4196368)
- [Multidimensional array iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739)

you can also extend the TreeIterator's `current()` method to provide additional markup:

```
class LinkedRecursiveTreeIterator extends RecursiveTreeIterator
{
    public function current()
    {
        return str_replace(
            $this->getInnerIterator()->current(),
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>',
                $this->getInnerIterator()->current()
            ),
            parent::current()
        );
    }
}

$treeIterator = new LinkedRecursiveTreeIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir'),
    LinkedRecursiveTreeIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

foreach($treeIterator as $val) echo $val, PHP_EOL;
```

The above will print the regular ASCII tree the `TreeIterator` prints but will wrap the filename into hyperlinks. Note that `$this->getInnerIterator()->current()` returns File objects, so you can access any other file properties, like filesize, last modified, etc, as well.

Comment: this is it! had a hard time looking for a way to access file details as the documentation does not say much.