# How do you scan the directory case insensitive?

Tags: php

I want to get files from a directory. And I don't if it is uppercase or lowercase. How do I scan the directory case insensitive in php?

```
strtolower(scandir($directory, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING)); ???
```

Comment: but a!=A any more than z=A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scandir()` returns an array, `strtolower()` only works on strings. You need to use `array_map()` to run the function on all the names returned:

```
$filenames = array_map('strtolower', scandir($directory));
```

Since the sorting done by `scandir` is case-sensitive, you should sort `$filenames` after you retrieve them.

```
sort($filenames);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know much about php. And I can hardly debug it. So it's difficult to see what I'm doing wrong too.

Comment: I try this $result = array_map('strtolower', scandir($directory, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING)); And this works too.

Comment: That will sort the names case-sensitively.

Answer (score 1):

This one preserves the upper and lower case in the array but sorts it case insensitive.

```
$filenames = scandir($directory, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
natcasesort($filenames);
```