# After using usort on a DirectoryIterator, method calls don't seem to work anymore

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that removes the oldest files based on date, for a max of 30 files. I grab all the files in the dir. If there are more than 30, they get sorted by date. Then the oldest gets deleted.

```
public function cleanUpFolder($path){
    $files = [];
    try {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
            if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
                $files[] = $fileinfo;
                // in here i can call any valid method like getPathname()
            }
        }
        $fileCount = count($files);
        if($fileCount > self::MAX_BACKUPS){
            // sort with the youngest file first
            usort($files, function($a, $b) {
                // in here, i can call functions like getMTime()
                // and even getPath()
                // but getPathname or getFileName return false or ""
                return $a->getMTime() < $b->getMTime();
            });
            for($i = $fileCount - 1; $i > 30; $i--){
                unlink($files[$i]->getPathname());
            }
        }        
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is working

1. Getting the files

What is not working

1. Sort? I cannot tell if the sort works
2. Calling some methods on the DirectoryIterator while looping through the `$files` array

It seems like putting the `$fileInfo` into an array, most function calls no longer work..

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `$files` array's values got messed up outside of the foreach loop. A `var_dump` of the array showed all the values were empty, which is odd. Not really a solution, but a workaround I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337096/list-and-sort-files-with-php-directoryiterator):

```
$files = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $files[] = array(
            "pathname" => $fileinfo->getPathname(),
            "modified" => $fileinfo->getMTime()
        );
    }
}
```

and then your `usort` becomes:

```
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['modified'] < $b['modified'];
});
```

and your `unlink` becomes:

```
for($i = $fileCount - 1; $i > 30; $i--){
    unlink($files['pathname']);
}
```

=== EDIT ===

I'm not expert in PHP so this could be wrong, but the top comment of [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) could be a clue as to why the methods are returning empty.

> When you iteterate using DirectoryIterator each "value" returned is
>   the same DirectoryIterator object. The internal state is changed so
>   when you call isDir(), getPathname(), etc the correct information is
>   returned. If you were to ask for a key when iterating you will get an
>   integer index value.
>
> FilesystemIterator (and RecursiveDirectoryIterator) on the other hand
>   returns a new, different SplFileInfo object for each iteration step.
>   The key is the full pathname of the file. This is by default. You can
>   change what is returned for the key or value using the "flags"
>   arguement to the constructor.