# How to Sort A-->Z when reading/selecting file names from folder

Tags: php

This might be very obvious however I cannot seem to solve it.

I have the following option menu :

```
<select name="Image2" onChange="showImage(this.value)">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
     $dir = "../somefolder";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
  echo "<option value='". $filename . "'>" . $filename . "</option>";  }
    sort($files);
 ?>

</select> 
<div id="image_div"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showImage(value)
 {
  var img = "<img src='../somefolder/"+value+"' />";
  document.getElementById('image_div').innerHTML = img;
 }
</script>
```

Which works fine, but all the files are not sorted a-->z is there a way to do this, I have over 100 files in this folder?
Any help Welcome

Comment: You could use [`glob('../somefolder/*')`](http://php.net/glob) instead.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: Instead of using opendir/readdir use [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) which sorts alphabetically by default

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076881/after-using-files-new-directoryiterator-in-php-how-do-you-sort-the-items

Comment: Your code is almost correct. First you get files in folder, then you use sort(), then you loop to create options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do two loops, one to read the filenames, and other to output them.

Since you have about 100 files, it will not change the response time...

```
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
}
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $filename){
     echo "<option value='". $filename . "'>" . $filename . "</option>";
}
```